# Excel Macro: Copy all rows to a new sheet when the date in column L is within 1 month of today's date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problems with this code. The macro is designed to search column L in Sheet 1, and if it identifies a date within this column, it should copy the entire row to Sheet 3.

Any pointers / corrections would be greatly appreciated :)

```
Sub datecompare()
Dim iMatches As Long
For Each cell In Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("L:L")
    ' If (Len(cell.Value) = 0) Then Exit For
    ' If DateDiff("m", Date, cell.Value) < 1 Then iMatches = (iMatches + 1)
        Worksheets(Sheet1).Rows(cell.Row).Copy Worksheets(Sheet3).Rows(iMatches)
    ' End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you range of interest is not really the whole "L" column, you could name the range in your Excel sheet (as `date_range`) and refer to this as a range object in your VBA. If it really is the whole column, then just uncomment the second `set` and comment out the first.

```
    Sub datecompare()
    Dim iMatches As Long
    Dim named_range As Range

    Set named_range = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("date_range")
    'Set named_range = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L:L")


For Each cell In named_range
    If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
        If DateDiff("m", Date, cell.Value) < 1 Then
            iMatches = (iMatches + 1)
            'Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(cell.Row).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(iMatches)
        End If
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

**Update**: To test if cell is a date, as you asked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First put `Sheet1` and `Sheet3` in double quotes ... they need to be strings ... without quotes VBA interprets them as variables which are undefined

Second bring back the 2nd commented `If` and move the increment of `iMatches` in a line of its own. Right now the increment is the only instruction done when the `If` evaluates to true, and the copy thereafter is executed every time - before you hit another error on the unmatched `End If` (if you uncomment it) or you try to insert into Sheet3 row 0, as iMatch has never been incremented.